# How to resolve conflicts in xcode 4 when using SVN?

Tags: iphone, ios, svn, xcode4

On trying to update my working copy, Xcode indicates that there are certain conflicts. A new screen comes up which shows my local file on the left and the server code on the right highlighting whatever conflicts are present. What I'm doing at this stage is, reviewing my code and make necessary changes using this tool: 
[image]

When I'm finally done reviewing and making changes to my code as necessary, I'd like to update my project with the changes I've made. However the update button at the bottom is still disabled. What is it that I'm missing here? How do I convey to Xcode that I'm done making changes and it may update the project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After making changes to your code, you have to right click your file and select 'resolve conflicts.'

I hope this may help.

Comment: I don't see any such option. What am I missing?

Comment: @AtulGoyal try by installing command line tools (Xcode->Preferences->Downloads->instll command line tools).

Answer (score 3):

You have click on a very line that shows conflict and resolve it explicitly by choosing either left or right version. After that update button will be enabled.

Answer (score 2):

First update your working copy to repository. If you are not finding any conflicts then commit the code. But if you have any conflicts, then those conflicts are indicated by red color. Click on that file (to see the conflicts use (cmd+d)), then click on resolve button to find the conflicts. After that there are some options that you want to select the exact code you want by choosing the options at the bottom: left, right, left right first, right left first,neither.

Then select the required code and click resolved button.
If your repository copy is correct then Go to resolve... >Identify conflicts... >Go to differences... >Resolve them.
If your working copy is correct then Go to resolve... >Identify conflicts... >Resolve them.